# How to make randomly pop some gui without stopping the script #python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, random, tkinter

I'm relatively new to python, so please bear with me.

My question has two aspects:

- First, I'm trying to make a GUI that randomly pops  different sentences to the user, every time in a new frame.
- Second, I want the user to be able to close the GUI without stopping the script, like if it was running in the background.

here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random
number = random.randint(0,13)

sentence = {contains 13 sentences
    }

window = tk.Tk()

window.output = tk.Label(text = sentence[number])
window.title("I Always See You")
window.geometry("300x150")

def next():
    rand= random.randint(0, 13)
    window2 = tk.Tk()
    window2.output = tk.Label(text = sentence[rand])
    window2.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
    window2.title("I Always See You")
    window2.geometry("300x150")

window.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)

choice()

window.after(1000, next)
window.mainloop()
```

My problem: when my second frame pops, there isn't any text showing, and if it does have something popping, it appears in the first frame.

also, how can you insert a random float in .after() ?

Thank you so much for your help!

cheers

Comment: What's the `choice()` function?

Comment: use `Toplevel()` to create popup window - tkinter should have only one `Tk()` winfow

Comment: why do you need `float` in `after` ? If you want to use it as time then it make no sense because it uses milliseconds so you need only integer values - ie. 500 (milliseconds) instead if  0.5 (seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not see the text in the second window because Tkinter cannot handle two main windows. You need to use the `Toplevel` class for the others. In addition, you haven't specified the parent of the label in `next`, so it will probably be packed inside `window` instead of `window2`.

In addition, you need 14 sentences because `randint`, unlike `randrange` includes both end points.

To set a random time in `after`, just use `randint` because it expects an integer number of ms.

To achieve what you want I suggest you to create a main window that will be withdraw (it will run in the background). Then popup Toplevels with random sentences. You need to call again `after` inside the `next` function if you want the windows to keep poping up. To prevent the `after` to be cancelled if the user closes the Toplevel, I called the `after` method from the withdrawn main window:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random
number = random.randint(0,13)

sentence = {i: str(i) for i in range(14)}

def next():
    rand=random.randint(0, 13)
    window2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window2.output = tk.Label(window2, text=sentence[rand])
    window2.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
    window2.title("I Always See You")
    window2.geometry("300x150")
    tps = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    root.after(tps, next)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw() # hide root window

window = tk.Toplevel(root)

window.output = tk.Label(window, text=sentence[number])
window.title("I Always See You")
window.geometry("300x150")
window.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)

tps = random.randint(1000, 10000)
root.after(tps, next)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly this! I was wondering, if I am doing a stand-alone script with py2exe, should I include an exit button or does the ctrl-c works? Sorry for the extra question :)

Comment: I don't know, I am using linux, not windows. If you don't put any exit button, the user can still stop the app from the taskmanager I think.